# Vertically centre multi-line text over an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get some caption text to be vertically positioned in the middle of an image. I've tried a whole bunch of different techniques using `table-cells` and what-not, but can't seem to get it to work!

I have the a `<li>` with a nested `<a>` and nested `<img>` & `div.caption-wrapper`. I've sized the caption wrapper to be the same size as the `<img>` but can't seem to get the `div.caption-wrapper` to position itself over the `<img>`

Obviously I need to get on top of the basics, but [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oldo_nicho/fr1j44yj/) of where I'm at. Any chance someone could suggest a solution?

Comment: With display table: https://jsfiddle.net/1agdkamu/, with translateY: https://jsfiddle.net/1agdkamu/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/45ogwwm9/)

Add the following css to `.caption-wrapper`:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transorm: translateY(-50%); /* for Chrome */
position: absolute;
left: 0;
display: inline-block;
```

Also, remove the `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` properties from `.caption-wrapper`.

Comment: I think translateY is the best solution as you don't need to know the dimensions of the img. Here's an updated and cleaned up fiddle that shows how: https://jsfiddle.net/1agdkamu/1/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Tarun. Breathing a big sigh of relief and happy to be moving forward again... :-)

Comment: Also, nice fiddle and tidy implementation @powerbuoy. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option with `position: absolute` and **Flexbox**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.caption-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
  <li class="grid-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://oldo-nicho.com/img/services/2.jpg" alt="img01"/>
      <div class="caption-wrapper">
        <span class="grid-caption">Caption text! Caption! Caption!</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I'll go with Tarun's suggestion as I'd like to maximise browser compatibility and from what I understand IE8/9 do not support flexbox. I'm definitely interested in flexbox though so I might have a bit more of a read up on it. Thanks again.